# @@TRANCOUNT and a current connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Assume I connect to SQL server 2008 via SQL Server Management Studio ( SSMS ) and open new window `W1` by clicking on New Query tab and write the following inside W1:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
```

If I execute this statement 5 times, and then write (inside `W1`)

```
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
```

, then the value returned will be 5. But if I open another window `W2` ( inside the same SSMS instance and thus on the same connection ) and write inside W2

```
SELECT @@TRANCOUNT;
```

then value returned will be 0.

> @@TRANCOUNT  variable returns the number of active transactions for the current connection.

Both W1 and W2 windows were opened on the same connection, so shouldn’t ( according to the above quote ) in both `W1` and `W2` variable @@TRANCOUNT hold the same value?

thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every query window in SSMS is a **separate** connection, running on a separate spid.  The number in parenthesis in the query window tab is your connection number for the current window.

With a couple windows open, and open transactions in each if you like, you should be able to see each one of them show up in the results of a call to sp_who2.  Using the spid number from the window tab you'll be able to find each row in the results of that proc.  You can also find detailed information about your connection in the status bar at the bottom of each query window, and also in the properties window for each open query window.

Comment: So opening W1 and W2 inside particular SSMS instance is basically the same ( as far as the scope of variables like @@TRANCOUNT is concerned ) as opening W1 and W2 inside different SSMS instances?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Each window is a separate connection regardless of which instance of SSMS it lives in.