# SqlConnection Create transaction automatic in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

Recently I have got a problem with Transaction in store procedure. I tried those code below for test and the results made me very confused.

```
CREATE PROC proc_TranTest
AS
    BEGIN
        --record initial TranCount 
        INSERT INTO [DebugLog]([Action], [ExtralInfo], [LogTime]) 
        VALUES('tran', 'after begin:' + STR(@@TRANCOUNT), GETDATE())    

        SET XACT_ABORT ON

        BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        --now we begin a new tran
        INSERT INTO [DebugLog]([Action], [ExtralInfo], [LogTime]) 
        VALUES('tran', 'after tran begin:' + STR(@@TRANCOUNT), GETDATE())   

        COMMIT TRANSACTION 
        --record trancount after our tran is committed
        INSERT INTO [DebugLog]([Action], [ExtralInfo], [LogTime]) 
        VALUES('tran', 'after tran commit:' + STR(@@TRANCOUNT), GETDATE())
        RETURN 1
    END
```

as we can see, I've just record the value or @@TRANCOUNT at different time.
First, I just used `EXEC [proc_TranTest]` , and the result was totally normal: 0-1-0,

then I tried to call the procedure from C# code, use a sqlconnection, and the result was 2-3-2. That's very strange to me ! I didn't use any transaction in program , so where is the transaction from ?

then I used a sqltransaction in the sqlconnection, while the result was still 2-3-2.

I've searched a long time and read many articles related, but I didn't found any instructions about this situation(well, there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776062/trancount-and-a-current-connection), but nested trans is used in that problem, while I didn't use it here.). The formal document in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.100).aspx) didn't give me much help on this either.

so, my question is , why the @@TRANCOUNT is 2 when I used C# code to connect the db and call the sp ? shouldn't it be 0(with no sqltrans)or 1(with sqltrans)? is the ADO.NET or the db create a transaction automatic when the connection begin? or is there something can be configured to do those things that i didn't noticed ?

by the way, I used .net 4.0 in vs2013, and sql server 2008 r2.

thanks very much.

Comment: @@TRANCOUNT in my ADO.NET tests works as expected. Try to use your problem code in simple test console app to identify problem area.

Comment: @Ruslan K. Thanks for your comment, and sorry for late response. I've just tried again, use EXEC [proc_TranTest], and I found it's still strange. while I use Print @@TRANCOUNT , the result shows 0-1-0, while when i insert the @@trancount into a table ,the resule is 2-3-2, is the insert statement create a transaction and dispose it  automatic ?